# How to access a request attribute set by a servlet in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I'm trying to retrieve attribute values set by a servlet in a JSP page, but I've only luck with parameters by `${param}`. I'm not sure about what can I do different. Maybe its simple, but I couldn't manage it yet.

```
public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    //there's no "setParameter" method for the "request" object
    request.setAttribute("attrib", "attribValue");

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Test.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

In the JSP I have been trying to retrieve the "attribValue", but without success:

```html
<body>
    <!-- Is there another tag instead of "param"??? -->
    <p>Test attribute value: ${param.attrib}
</body>
```

If I pass a parameter through all the process (invoking page, servlets and destination page), it works quite good.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's available in the default EL scope already, so just

```
${attrib}
```

should do.

If you like to explicitly specify the scope (EL will namely search the page, request, session and application scopes in sequence for the first non-null attribute value matching the attribute name), then you need to refer it by the scope map instead, which is `${requestScope}` for the request scope

```
${requestScope.attrib}
```

This is only useful if you have *possibly* an attribute with exactly the same name in the page scope which would otherwise get precedence (but such case usually indicate poor design after all).

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

Comment: And how can I get the same attribute in a CSS file?

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a comparison between `EL` syntax and `scriptlet` syntax will help you understand the concept.

- `param` is like `request.getParameter()`
- `requestScope` is like `request.getAttribute()`

You need to tell `request attribute` from `request parameter`.

Comment: Thanks! This helps, unknowingly we think requestScope is similar to request object itself, rather than request.getAttribute( ).

Answer (score 4):

have you tried using an expression tag?

```
<%= request.getAttribute("attrib") %>
```

Comment: I've considered using it, but I prefer using the ${sth} convention, if it would be possible.

Comment: scriptlet is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

If the scope is of request type, we set the attribute using **`request.setAttribute(key,value)`** in request and retrieve using **`${requestScope.key}`** in jsp .