# How to output data from servlet to jsp without JSTL and EJB

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a task to make following:
1. User enters their login and password. I did following jsp for that:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<div id="main">
    <aside class="leftAside">
        <h2>Authorization section</h2>
        <p>Please enter your login and password and press "Go!"</p>
    </aside>
    <section>
        <article>
            <h1>Authorization</h1>
            <div class="text">
                <form method="GET" action="authorization">
                    <p>
                        <label for="login">Login</label>
                        <input type="text" name="login" id="login"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <button type="submit">Go!</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

1. If OK, they get back the history of visits, if not - login page again with some mark that authorization failed.
   I made all connections and queries, but how to manage it and how to output all data to jsp? I should not use beans and jstl, just pure servlets.

my servlet is below, and I don't understand neither how to get passwd and login from the user to send it further.

```
package Controller;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.*;


@WebServlet(name = "controller", loadOnStartup=1, urlPatterns = {"/"})
public class web_controller extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String userPath=request.getServletPath();
        if ("/".equals(userPath)){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else {}
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

    }
    private static Connection getSQLConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPwd = "root";
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPwd);
            return connection;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    private static ResultSet history(Connection connection, String user) {
        ResultSet result = null;
        int userID = 0;
        try{
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user);
            result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                userID = result.getInt("id");
            }
            result = null;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            PreparedStatement history = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM history WHERE login=?");
            getHistory.setInt(1, userID);
            result = history.executeQuery();
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
    }

    private static int USER_NOT_FOUND = 2;
    private static int WRONG_PWD = 0;
    private static int SUCCESS = 1;

    private static int checkUser(Connection connection, String user, String passwd) {
        ResultSet result = null;
        String pwdMD5 = getMD5(passwd);
        try{
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user);
            result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                String storedPwd = result.getString("passwd");
                if (storedPwd.equals(pwdMD5)) {
                    return SUCCESS;
                }
                else return WRONG_PWD;
            } else return USER_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static void addEntry(HttpServletRequest request, Connection connection, String user, String passwd, int success) {
        int userID = 0;

        try{
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user);
            ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            result.next();
            userID = result.getInt("id");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            PreparedStatement updHistory = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO history (user_id, success, ipaddr) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            updHistory.setInt(1, userID);
            updHistory.setInt(2, success);
            updHistory.setString(3, request.getRemoteAddr());
            ResultSet result = updHistory.executeQuery();
            result = updHistory.executeQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static String getMD5(String pwd) {
        String generatedMD5 = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(pwd.getBytes());
            byte[] bytes = md.digest();
            StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
            {
                sbuilder.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            generatedMD5 = sbuilder.toString();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return generatedMD5;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get passwd and login from the user to send it further?

Try with [ServletRequest#getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

Sample code

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
}
```

---

**Never send username/password via GET request due to security concern.**

use `<form method="POST" action="authorization">`

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
}
```

For more sample have a look at [How to transfer data from JSP to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971877/how-to-transfer-data-from-jsp-to-servlet)

---

--EDIT--

> how to pass the ResultSet from the servlet to the jsp?

Simply use [ServletRequest#setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [ServletRequest#getAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

Please have a look at below posts:

- [How to access at request attributes in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912690/how-to-access-at-request-attributes-in-jsp)
- [How to access a request attribute set by a servlet in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898393/how-to-access-a-request-attribute-set-by-a-servlet-in-jsp)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. But how to output data from database to jsp?

Comment: I never suggest you to use it but try with script lets `<% JAVA CODE %>`. you can say `<% out.print("abc"); %>`

Comment: I know about script lets, and that it's discouraged, but is it the only way? Then could you please show how to pass the ResultSet from the servlet to the jsp?

Comment: what have you said in your post **I should not use beans and jstl, just pure servlets.**

Comment: @Battle_Slug Now you are diverting from your actual question.

Comment: @Battle_Slug still let me update my post to answer **how to pass the ResultSet from the servlet to the jsp?**

Comment: No, I had two questions, and now you answered both. I appreciate, will try to implement.