# Pass parameters to jsp by <%@ include file

Tags: java, jsp, include

I need to pass params to included jsp

```
 <%@ include file="second.jsp" %>
```

i need to use it several times in one jsp page, so i need to pass id.
I can't use jsp:include because jsp can't see struts action in this way

Can u help me? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set them as attributes on the request object (which makes them visible to the `${var}` syntax) before invoking your include.

See [How to access a request attribute set by a servlet in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898393/how-to-access-a-request-attribute-set-by-a-servlet-in-jsp) for a similar question.