# I am trying get data from Servlet to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, frontend

I am trying get data from Servlet page to jsp page but i am getting null value.
i want to get the message which is there in servlet page. 
please help me in this
below is my code
servlet:

```
package com.project1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public TestServlet() {
        super();

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String  msg="hi i am servlet";

        request.setAttribute("data",msg);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Test.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<%= request.getAttribute("data") %>.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a request attribute set by a servlet in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898393/how-to-access-a-request-attribute-set-by-a-servlet-in-jsp)

Comment: I tried the same but Im not getting the message from servlet

Comment: request.getRequestDispatcher("Test.jsp").forward(request, response);
Do you think this is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.
servlet.

You have missed *@override* in doGet method.

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        String msg = "hi i am servlet";

        request.setAttribute("data", msg);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Test.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <%=request.getAttribute("data")%>.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe add

> @WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TestServlet"})

to the top of the servlet