# How to render jspf dynamically in jsp page and how I can pass parameters to it?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-7

I'm trying to render multiple jsf on a single jsp page based on some condition and based on some JS event. Parameters are also needed to be set which I can get through ajax call. My problem is I'm not able to pass the parameters to jspf and not able to render it in jsp through JS.

Right now jspf is included as follows :-

```
<c:if test="<%= MyPermissionUtil.contains(permissionChecker, Quote.class.getName(), 0, themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), ActionKeys.UPDATE_MARGIN) %>">
  <div class="cpq--margin-percentage">
    <%@ include file="/fragments/margin_percentage.jspf" %>
  </div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the attribute before including as a request object and it will be visible like `${variable}`?
Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898393/how-to-access-a-request-attribute-set-by-a-servlet-in-jsp)